# HIVE join issue

Tags: exception, join, hadoop, hive

I have a Hive installation (Hive-0.8, Hadoop-1.0.3) over 5 machines and whenever I try to join two tables I get the following Exception:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while reading from task log url 
>    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.errors.TaskLogProcessor.getErrors(TaskLogProcessor.java:130)
>    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.JobDebugger.showJobFailDebugInfo(JobDebugger.java:211)
>    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.JobDebugger.run(JobDebugger.java:81)
>    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http:// hadoop4:50060/tasklog?taskid=attempt_201210161122_0013_r_000001_4&start=-8193

The url can point to a different machine.

So I found by googling that if I change `taskid` to `attemptid` then I can see the actual problem, which is this Exception:

> FATAL ExecReducer: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: nanos > 999999999 or < 0
>       at java.sql.Timestamp.setNanos(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.io.TimestampWritable.populateTimestamp(TimestampWritable.java:348)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.io.TimestampWritable.toString(TimestampWritable.java:320)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazyTimestamp.writeUTF8(LazyTimestamp.java:95)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazyUtils.writePrimitiveUTF8(LazyUtils.java:232)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe.serialize(LazySimpleSerDe.java:427)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe.serializeField(LazySimpleSerDe.java:381)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe.serialize(LazySimpleSerDe.java:365)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.processOp(FileSinkOperator.java:569)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.process(Operator.java:471)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:762)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.processOp(SelectOperator.java:84)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.process(Operator.java:471)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:762)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FilterOperator.processOp(FilterOperator.java:132)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.process(Operator.java:471)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:762)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.CommonJoinOperator.genAllOneUniqueJoinObject(CommonJoinOperator.java:749)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.CommonJoinOperator.checkAndGenObject(CommonJoinOperator.java:836)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.JoinOperator.endGroup(JoinOperator.java:263)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecReducer.reduce(ExecReducer.java:198)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:519)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:420)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)

I am not sure if the entire stack trace is helpful, but what I found from googling, the exception was a link to an IBM update/fix of IBM DB2. I don't know if that relates to any Hive issues, and even if it did, I wouldn't know what to do.

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

PS: I have tried solutions that were suggested online for older versions of Hive/Hadoop but none of them resulted in anything.  Also, I have checked for `NULL` values as well.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better provide more information about your hive env. Such as you table schema and the original data.

In above exception you provided, the problem maybe the data your stored in hdfs is not matched with hive date column.

Comment: how can I cross check the hdfs with the hive date column?

btw. I figured out a temporary solution to my problem through the usage of views. For some reason if I put the query into a view then I can do whatever I want on the view and the exception never gets thrown.

Answer (score 0):

You really should provide the full sql. In any case the following is invalid:

```
nanos > 999999999 or < 0
```

Should be:

```
(nanos > 999999999 or nanos < 0)
```

So it would not be true that "in a view" works fine. You would have had to have corrected that syntax error as part of creating the view. IOW your view does *not* match the standalone query.